# Get the results sorted in the same order as values inside the in() field of select

Tags: oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

Is there is a way to order by the order of the values in an IN() clause?
I have a select query:

```
Select * from abc where xyz in (a list of values).
```

I want the result to be sorted in the same order as the list inside the bracket.

One way is that I can put the values in a temp table with an increasing sequence and then join the 2 tables, and then order by the sequence, but this is not a good way.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.
There is another approach, similar to a_horse_with_no_name's approach:

```
with t as 
(select t.*, rownum r from table (sys.odcinumberlist(val1, val2, val3...)) t)
select * from abc ac, t where ac.id = column_value and is_active = 'Y' order by r
```

This should work too. Which one do you guys think is the best and optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No need for a temp table (but not really pretty either)

```
with list_values (seqnr, id) as (
    select 1, 42 from dual
    union all
    select 2, 43 from dual
    union all
    select 3, 44 from dual
    -- you get the picture
)
select *
from abc
  join list_values lv on abc.xyz = lv.id
order by lv.seqnr
```

Comment: Your is "not really pretty", mine is "ugly"... Sensing a pattern here ;)

Comment: @Anonymous: the decode solution is also a "nice" idea. Didn't think of that one

Answer (score 1):

One ugly option is to use DECODE:

```
Select * from abc 
WHERE xyz in (a list of values) 
ORDER BY DECODE(xyz, 'val1', 1, 'val2', 2, ...)
```